# Error while connecting kinesis producer AWS kinesis 443

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis

Failed to open connection to monitoring.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:443 : certificate verify failed while connecting to AWS kinesis

```
public static KinesisProducer getKinesisProducer() {

    KinesisProducerConfiguration config = new KinesisProducerConfiguration();

    config.setCredentialsProvider(new DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain());         
    config.setRegion(REGION);
    config.setMaxConnections(10);
    config.setRequestTimeout(600000);
    config.setRecordMaxBufferedTime(15000); 

    KinesisProducer producer = new KinesisProducer(config);
    return producer;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please follow the below link:-

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/streams/latest/dev/developing-producers-with-sdk.html

As maybe this is an authentication problem. So try using the instruction from the official AWS instructions/ documentation.

Comment: We have to Change the version to get the Certificate to be verified in this case.   The reason behind this is given below........Please note that as from February 2018 Amazon Kinesis Data streams installed ATS certificates, 
thus in order to write records to Kinesis data streams using the KPL, you should upgrade your installation to KPL version 0.12.6 or higher [1],this change is for all regions. You are currently using version: 0.10.2.

Comment: Please go ahead and update the installation including dependencies in the project so we can test this in your environment,
additionally for more details about Amazon Trust Services (ATS),
you can refer to our public documentation in the reference link provided [2].